# How to assist users with cycles of high activity and low/no activity?

Tags: discussion, support

I am not a trilogy regular, not a StackExchange regular, nor a professional. Rather, I am an enthusiast, which for me means that my activity on this exchange ebbs and flows with the time I have to dedicate to a hobby of cooking. Does that mean I am in the wrong place? If not, how can we make this more useful to people like myself?

Case in point: I can't seem to easily find my old questions. In principle, it seems like on a cooking site, marking a question as answered is going to take more turn-around time than a programming question (vetting the answer in many cases should mean actually trying them out, which means the whole process of cooking, and opposed to simply trying some lines of code). Besides that, I may not check my answers until the next I am trying the same technique that posed problems for me before, etc.

Is there a reason I can't easily see my old questions? Was that a design aspect of the tech-centric trilogy? Is it appropriate for Food & Cooking?

It is entirely possible that I am misunderstanding the Q&A dynamics of a programming-centric site in contrast to cooking. It is also possible that I missed the obvious way of viewing old questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have missed the obvious way.

Simply click on your username at the top of the page to access this page:

https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/users/670/matt-broerman

Comment: ah, complete beginner oversight--didn't see that meta and cooking user pages didn't cite same questions. Apologies.

Comment: Note that [Googling youself + site:cooking.stackexchange.com](http://www.google.nl/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Matt+Broerman+site:cooking.stackexchange.com) does a great job of finding your activity on the site.